# Reading contents of CSV file not getting the last updated information

Tags: php, file, caching, fopen, cdn

I update information on data.csv using:

```
function generateCsv($data, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"') {
   $dataPath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/test-los-goya-2015/alfombra-roja/data.csv';
   $handle = fopen($dataPath, 'r+');
   @ftruncate($handle, 0);
   foreach ($data as $line) {
           fputcsv($handle, $line, $delimiter, $enclosure);
   }
   fclose($handle);
```

And then, when the user clicks on the Publish button, I do:

```
   function publishCsv () {
   $dataPath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/test-los-goya-2015/alfombra-roja/data.csv';
   $dataPublishedPath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/test-los-goya-2015/alfombra-roja/data-published.csv';
   copy($dataPath, $dataPublishedPath);
```

}

And then the information is visible right away on front. However, the updated information on data.csv is not visible on backoffice until about 10 minutes have passed.

We are using Level 3 CDN which holds strong caching, however, the information retrieval is always done to http://origin-...., like this piece of code I have when I read information from data.csv (backoffice) and data-published.csv (front):

```
  if (!$getPublished) {
    $dataPath = 'http://origin-lab.rtve.es/test-los-goya-2015/alfombra-roja/data.csv';
  } else {
    $dataPath = 'http://origin-lab.rtve.es/test-los-goya-2015/alfombra-roja/data-published.csv';
  }
  $aLines = file( $dataPath );
```

How is it possible that getting the information from the csv files, being exactly the same way, shows updated information on the front, but not on backoffice?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I check everytime I click on Save and/or Publish, and the files are updated correctly on the server.

Comment: why don't you post the real code? not just fake algorithm? `$dataPath = 'http://origin-xxxxxxxxx/data.csv';` so when you `write line` what kind of command do you use? when you `copy(data.csv, data-published.csv)` is it `data.csv` or `$dataPath` ??? show the code, we mustn't guess to help you

Comment: You are right Kim, I didn't post the full url because it is something running on production that is really not functional. But I really need the help so I edited all the code.

Comment: now you just posted code that creates LOCAL file on your local machine, we can't see any CDN calls here.  and again: `copy(data.csv, data-published.csv)` is it `data.csv` or `$dataPath` ??? so now we see something, but absolutely not enough to help

Comment: ok, now we can see how you create your local copy of the file, and now the question is how is your local folder is linked, assigned or binded with CDN ?

Comment: There you go. What I meant by CDN is that the website is hosted on a Level 3 Content Delivery Network. I believe that this solution is keeping several copies of the website so the ones "closer" to the user are cached. When you throw a http://origin-.... request, you go straight to the server that keeps the original data.

Comment: you must have some API documentation how to push files and avoid outdated cache or change/invalidate  file status by some request. what CDN provider is? do you have public link to their srvice? let me read about this CDN

Comment: You are totally right Kim. I read that information yesterday and found out that invalidation can only be achieved from their website (mediaportal.level3.com) and it seems that we don't have access to do the needed request.

Comment: so you is a customer of http://www.level3.com/ ? what service do you use? where is a link to documentation for developers ?

Comment: Here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8NT9hPIYUzmcU1MTkpjSDViVlJNOEwyYy1acGdzdE5IX0hN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: so here you have your API to call invalidate request. you need to call that right after your `copy()` command.

Comment: But the way I see it, I need some sort of ID, something that identifies my site, for example: https://ws.level3.com/invalidations/v1.0/12345/BBBN56789/lab.rtve.es?notification=ricardo.martinez@mail.com

Comment: yes sure, you must have some credentials